# Nova Filters - filter a resource with a belongsTo relationship?

Tags: laravel, filter, laravel-nova

How can i create a Nova filter that will allow me to filter my Question resource by another resource called Module?

The question belongsTo to the module (module_id is FK on Questions).

So for the apply method i have:

```
public function apply(Request $request, $query, $value)
{
    return $query->where('module_id', $value);
}
```

I'm struggling with the options method. I would like to have the module->name as the key and the module->id as the value but would like to display all modules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Module `model` to retrieve all & use collection method `pluck` to get name => id as key value pair.

```
public function options(Request $request)
{
    $models = \App\Module::all();
    return $models->pluck('id', 'name')->all();
}
```

Comment: This approach might not be ideal if you have a lot of rows in the `modules` table.